# nrpe check_load results in unknown error?

Tags: monitoring, nagios, icinga

I'm using the nagios check_load plugin.

I have the following  line in my `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg`

```
command[check_load]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_load -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
```

And on my icinga server in `/etc/icinga/objects/localhost_icinga.cfg` I have the following service definition

```
define service{
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       prod-01
        service_description             Prod Load
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_load!15,10,5!30,25,20
}
```

When I check my icinga dashboard it lists this check as a pink colored, unknown error.  Is there anything I need to change in my configuration to get everything to work correctly?

Comment: What is the definition of the "check_nrpe" command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the command on the server with the same arguments and see if it responds. it will tell you the error or if it's an unknown error chances are you just need to either enable sudo with no password for user nagios OR chmod 4755 and ownership root:nagios the check script.

Comment: I ran `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H <client ip> -c check_load -a 15,10,5 30,25,20` and the output was fine.

Comment: I meant on the server in question ssh to it and run 
`/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_load -w 15,10,5 -c 30,25,20`
as a regular user and see if it errors.

Comment: I tried that as well and it worked

Comment: "enable sudo with no password for user nagios" is potentially very dangerous advice

Comment: i'd have to agree keith, i usually forget that most don't read the config file where it says to include the path to the checkdir

Answer (score 0):

In `nrpe.cfg` on your target system, is `dont_blame_nrpe` set to 1?

What do the logs on your Icinga server say?

Answer (score 0):

Your check_command is slightly wrong. You have `check_nrpe!check_load!15,10,5!30,25,20`, which is passing "15,10,5" as ARG2 and "30,15,20" as ARG3, but your command is written to only use ARG2.

You can just change `check_nrpe!check_load!15,10,5!30,25,20`
 to `check_nrpe!check_load!"15,10,5 30,25,20"` (or change your `command[check_load]` line to use both ARG2 and ARG3).